# Error Catching in Powershell Security Group Script

Tags: powershell

Making a script at work to save some time getting approval from a Security Group owner when someone requests access to a group.

It works OK, but not great. The idea is to create a draft in Outlook2010 that is auto-filled with SG Manager Email address, Subject entered by Analyst. The body contains the requesting users Office, Dept, Manager, and Job title.

It does all this fine, but there is zero error catching, so for example, if the group name entered by the Analyst is wrong or annoyingly has a space at the end, it retains the information saved in the `$managerEmail` from last time you run it (I thought `-like` would sort this, but it does not).

Also, it only works for one user, one group, one email - where in reality there could be multiple users requesting access or a user requesting access to multiple groups.  I'm looking for a hint in the right direction - would I need to employ a loop of some kind in it to accept multiple inputs and create multiple Email drafts?

It's a mash of bits of scripts together with my own extremely novice "code" so I'm sure there are parts that do nothing of value so any cleanup advise would also be appreciated, I'm not sensitive about it so any thoughts please share.

```
Get-Module -ListAvailable
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

#Below is user inputs required
$User = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input the user name'
$Group = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input Group Name'
$Notify = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input Notify Subject Line'

#Below is the user info
Get-ADUser -Filter {name -like $user}
if ($User -ne $null)
{
    $Find = Get-ADUser $User -Server americas.cshare.net –Properties * |
        Select-Object Office, Department, Name, Manager, Title

    $Office = $Find.Office
    $Dept = $Find.Department
    $Title = $Find.Title
    $Name = $Find.Name
    $Usermanager = $Find.Manager
}

$UM = (get-aduser -Identity $Usermanager -Server americas.cshare.net -Properties Name);
$UserManagerName = $UM.Name;

#Below is get owner name and email need to add error catching
Get-ADGroup -Filter {name -like $Group} -Server americas.cshare.net -Properties ManagedBy |
    ForEach-Object {
        $managedBy = $_.ManagedBy;
        if ($managedBy -ne $null)
        {
            $manager = (get-aduser -Identity $managedBy -Server americas.cshare.net -Properties emailAddress);
            $managerName = $manager.Name;
            $managerEmail = $manager.emailAddress;
        }
        else
        {
            $managerName = 'N/A';
            $managerEmail = 'N/A';
        }

        Write-Output $_;
    } |
    Select-Object -Property @(
        @{n = 'Group Name'; e = {$_.Name}}
        @{n = 'Managed By Name'; e = {$managerName}}
        @{n = 'Managed By Email'; e = {$managerEmail}}
    )

#Below is the email part saves a draft to check yourself before sending
$ol = New-Object -comObject Outlook.Application
$mail = $ol.CreateItem(0)
$null = $Mail.Recipients.Add("$managerEmail")
$Mail.Subject = "$Notify"
$Mail.Body = @"
Dear $managerName,

$Name has requested to be added to the security group $Group


Job Role: $Title

Department: $Dept

Office: $Office

Manager: $UserManagerName



As the owner of $Group, can you review this request and approve/deny accordingly.



Please REPLY ALL when you respond.



Kind Regards,

Service Desk
"@

$Mail.Save()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I took a stab at it and added validation steps, but you don't really have much cause for "error handling" exactly.  Since this script depends on a lot of user input, I cleaned up that process.  Also addressed your problem with group searches.  The filter doesn't support `-match`, so I added proper wildcards on each end of the group name (to catch those various bits).  Not sure what the `Select-Object` was for at the end of your pipeline, but that's in there, too, in the form of `New-Object`.

```
Import-Module -Name ActiveDirectory


#region User details
do {
    $user = Read-Host -Prompt SID
    $adArgs = @{
        Identity    = $user
        Server      = 'americas.cshare.net'
        Properties  = 'Office','Department','Name','Manager','Title'
        ErrorAction = 'SilentlyContinue'
    }
    $user = Get-ADUser @adArgs

    if (-not $user) {
        'SID not found in Active Directory. Try again.'
    }
} until ($user)

$userName    = $user.Name
$userTitle   = $user.Title
$userDept    = $user.Department
$userOffice  = $user.Office
$userManager = Get-ADUser -Identity $user.Manager -Server americas.cshare.net -Properties Name |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
#endregion


#region Group details
do {
    $group = Read-Host -Prompt Group
    $adArgs = @{
        Filter      = "Name -like '*$group*'"
        Server      = 'americas.cshare.net'
        Properties  = 'ManagedBy'
        ErrorAction = 'SilentlyContinue'
    }
    $adGroup = Get-ADGroup @adArgs

    if (-not $adGroup) {
        'Group not found in Active Directory. Try again.'
    }

    if ($adGroup.Count -gt 1) {
        'Multiple groups found matching query. Try again.'
        $adGroup = $null
    }
} until ($adGroup)

try {
    $adArgs = @{
        Identity    = $adGroup.ManagedBy
        Server      = 'americas.cshare.net'
        Properties  = 'emailAddress'
        ErrorAction = 'Stop'
    }
    $groupManager = Get-ADUser @adArgs
} catch {
    "Failed to retrieve '$group' manager! $_" # prints the AD error
    Pause
    Exit
}

$groupManagerName  = $groupManager.Name
$groupManagerEmail = $groupManager.emailAddress
#endregion


$subject = Read-Host -Prompt Subject

New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{
    'Group Name'       = $group
    'Managed By Name'  = $groupManagerName
    'Managed By Email' = $groupManagerEmail
}


#region Draft an email
$ol = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$mail = $ol.CreateItem(0)
$null = $mail.Recipients.Add($groupManagerEmail)
$mail.Subject = $subject
$mail.Body = @"
Dear $groupManagerName,

$userName has requested to be added to the security group $group


Job Role:   $userTitle

Department: $userDept

Office:     $userOffice

Manager:    $userManager


As the owner of $group, can you review this request and approve/deny accordingly.

Please REPLY ALL when you respond.


Kind Regards,

Service Desk
"@

$mail.Save()
#endregion


Pause
```